# Drupal on IIS 7: URL Rewrite vs. ISAPI Rewrite modules

Tags: iis

I'm preparing to install Drupal 6 on an Win2k8 server. I'm still on the fence about using IIS 7 exclusively as the web server, or installing Apache and avoiding IIS 7 altogether. I work on a campus with a lot of different networks & system which mostly run on Windows servers, so I fear that not utilizing IIS 7 in some form may come back to bite me later on.

Anyway-one of the main issues I've seen from folks who've installed Drupal w/o Apache is in configuring clean URLs & URL rewriting. I'd like to ask if it is any easier setting up URL rewriting with the MS URL Rewrite vs. an ISAPI Rewrite module? Is there a major difference between the two modules other than that the full-feature ISAPI modules seem to cost money?

Thank you.

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out: [Clean URLs with IIS](https://drupal.org/node/3854)

> The best method is Microsoft's URL Rewrite Module for IIS7, available
>   via the Web Platform Installer on Windows Server 2008 and Vista.
>   Download and documentation are also available on Microsoft's IIS.Net
>   site. You can also use third party rewrite modules (see list above).

Comment: Thanks, Bart. I may end up having my employer purchasing Helicon ISAPI Rewrite _in case_ it makes URL rewriting during a website transition easier when lots of links may get screwed up.